# Create SOX batch script to extract first 15 seconds and rename multiple files in folder

Tags: shell-script, audio, mp3, sox

I have a folder with several MP3 files that I need to extract 10-15 seconds of audio from. I would also like to rename these by appending sample-(name).mp3 to the converted files.

How can I do this via Shell Script?

Comment: What is (name)? Is that the name of the mp3 file without `.mp3` (i.e. do you just want to stick `sample-` in front)? Or is that some data you get from the MP3 (via ID3)? What determines whether it is 10 or 15  seconds, or something in between? Do you know in advance, does it have to be random, is it a fixed amount that you don't know yet right now? Where should it start?

Comment: Anthon - multiple file names such as file-description-other.mp3, want the output to be sample-file-description-other.mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want/need to use `sox` for this you can use its `trim` command:

```
for i in *.mp3
do 
  sox "$i" sample-"$i" trim 0 10
done
```

The splitting you can also do with the commandline utility that is part of [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php). You explicitly set the output file with `-o`, so the originals are not touched, just remove them after you are done with them. This allows you to incorporate tags defined in the file in the output name than `sox` does (what you don't seem to need right now):

```
for i in *.mp3
do 
  mp3splt "$i" 00.00.00 00.10.00 -o sample-"${i%.mp3}"
done
```

Note that `-o` normally works with `@` based directives to include tag elements in the output name **and appends `.mp3`**. Without `${i%.mp3}` you would get `.mp3.mp3` files.

Times are dot separated, don't try to use `:` instead, you get a less than useful error message that you don't have enough split points.

I would not remove the input files until you have tested that the scripts works. Also note that if you stop it halfway, or add files later, that you cannot re-run it without removing any `sample-` files first. You might want to specify a directory before `sample-...`, to keep things apart.

Comment: Installed - any idea the CL syntax other than -o? Just need 0-10 seconds.

Comment: @DesignsEdge I updated it with the details for that. The tricky part is that `-o` normally takes some ID3 based `@` directives and appends `.mp3` which you have to cut

Comment: @DesignsEdge also put in a version that should work with `sox`

Comment: You are the man! But in a bash script and poof! Thanks for teaching me something new, it is much appreciated!